# How can I queue operations?

Tags: hacker-experience

I've heard that I can queue up operations to do them all at once. What's the benefit of this, and how can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two primary benefits of queuing operations is to minimize the time something is visible in a log file, and to escape a DDoS.

When you start any operation that is timed, the game automatically loads a special kind of Task Manager page that only shows the operation you just started.  **This is the only page on which that operation will auto-complete.**  To prevent it from automatically completing when the bar fills to 100%, just navigate away from the page before it completes.

- When you're messing about on a server where your changes might be noticed by another player (and therefore, your IP revealed to that player), **queue an "Edit Log File" operation that replaces the log with a blank one**.  When your other changes are done, go to the Task Manager, click "All Tasks", and click the Complete button for the other change, then *immediately* click the Edit Log File's Complete button.  The game will process them both back to back, hiding your changes within less than a second of you making them - meaning only players who load the log during that quarter-second will see your IP.
- If you **keep an IP reset already at 100% in your Task Manager**, when you become the target of a DDoS attempt or find yourself on the FBI's Most Wanted List, you can simply Complete the IP reset without the 10-minute wait time to escape.

*Example*:  Go to a server, crack it, log in, clear the log.  Start downloading a new hasher from that server, but DON'T stay on the page that says "Download Basic Hasher.hash (1.5) from 123.45.67.89" - instead, click the Logs button to view the site's log again.  Delete whatever is there (or put a single space at the beginning, if it's already blank!) and click the Edit log file button...  and, again, GET OFF THAT PAGE.  Go to your Task Manager instead.  Click All Files and wait until BOTH tasks are finished.  Then click the download's complete button, *immediately* followed by the edit's complete button.  The log that shows you downloading things from that server will only exist for a fraction of a second.

Note you can queue more than two items, if you don't mind the slowdown.  You can wait for three downloads and three deletions (and a log edit!) to finish, then click all the complete buttons in order (downloads first, then deletions, then the log file last) to instantly download AND delete three different files from a server without anyone seeing your IP in the logs.

TL;DR

> To queue an item to complete later, **simply navigate away from the page it brings you to when you start that operation**.  You can use this to hide logs super-fast or reset your IP without the 10-minute wait.